# Why XY + XZ + YZ can be simplified into XY + Z(X¬Y + ¬XY) in boolean algebra?

Tags: boolean, boolean-expression, simplify

I not understand why the first boolean expression on the question can be simplified into the last. Please help me.

Comment: I think this is not the right place to ask that.

Comment: This kind of thing does come up in some kinds of programming.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That does not mean it would not have been better off on math.

Comment: @JanHudec Meh, too trivial for bureaucracy. Such things don't need to be mutually exclusive, no pun intended :)

Comment: i am new here. Sorry if i post the question in a wrong place.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a math question rather than a programming question.

Comment: @user3368605 Don't let them discourage you. Boolean algebra is usually on-topic. Some folks just like "throwing the book."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XY + Z(X ⊕ Y)
= XY + Z(X¬Y + ¬XY)                           // Expand XOR operation
= XY + X¬YZ + ¬XYZ                            // Distribute AND over OR
= XYZ + XY¬Z + X¬YZ + ¬XYZ                    // Expand XY
= (XYZ + XY¬Z) + (XYZ + X¬YZ) + (XYZ + ¬XYZ)  // Copy XYZ and add parens
= XY + XZ + YZ                                // Remove trivial X+¬X = 1's
```

Reassembly is the reverse of disassembly.